# Integrating a Google Analytics Chart Within My Application

Tags: asp.net, charts, google-analytics

How do I integrate a Google Analytics chart displaying sessions and pageviews within my application?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/) to export data from Analytics. You can then use a custom charting library like [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) to display a chart from this data.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a nuget package that will let you do this.  It displays google analytics data using google charts - https://www.nuget.org/packages/GoogleAnalytics.GoogleCharts.NET/

If you have questions please feel free to reach out.